# Spec sheet notation: 2 dots between numbers

Tags: specifications

I was comparing spec sheets for the [AH3503](https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/1132644/AHNJ/AH3503/110/1/AH3503.html) and the [SS49E](https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/473135/SECELECTRONICS/SS49E/2354/2/SS49E.html) when I ran into notation I have never seen before: a number, followed by 2 dots, followed by another number. [image: notation]

What does this notation mean? Which one of these sensors is more sensitive?

Comment: Probably typo..

Comment: Almost certainly a typo as there is no other explanation that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought it might be a fancy way of writing scientific notation or something, but a typo makes more sense.

Comment: It's a range indication… in europe often instead of saying 12-18V (for example) often we use 12..18V, 12…18V;

Comment: I don't think that's the case here, because the numbers on the right are lower than the ones on the left. It doesn't make sense to say 7-5mV/mT for the minimum and 17-5mV/mT for the maximum

Answer (score 0):

```
  Sensitivity     9mA @ 5V                         1.6       1.8      2.0     mV/G
```

**1G =  0.1 mT  so 1.8 mV/G = 18 mV/T**

vs  [image]